specific content for specific user in the control panel?
I have woocomerce website, and the website owner askd me to do this
He want to sell training courses + the original products, and that is not an issue.
The issue is he wants that: after the user order and paid for that coarse, he will receive the training video just for him, no one else can see it, and its should be protected from sharing on the web.
or simply login to his account on wordpress and see the video he subscribed for, also without any option to share it on download it.
in other word, is there any chance to add the video to the user control panel so he can login and watch ? just like download center, you pay, login and download your content.
I hope you understand the idea, any advice to do that ? or something different maybe?
Thanks in advanced
